# Using a variable like $(ProjectDir) in Integration Services Package (.dtsx)

Tags: service, ssis, package, integration

Is this possible?

I have a package that needs to be copied to three 3 different servers. Each server is used for a different testing environment. All three servers have the same directory layout. The layout is as follows:
**\SERVER\ConfigFiles** <- Here go the .dtsConfig files.
**\SERVER\Packages** <- Here go the .dtsx files.

I want to be able to use the same package copied over the three 3 different servers without any modification. The only difference amongst the 3 servers would be the content inside the **.dtsConfig** file. The config files contain directories for the excel, log, and SQL server connection for each environment.

For example. Let's say I have a package called **Cars.dtsx**. This package is EXACTLY the same amongst all three servers. The package file points to a **.dtsConfig** file that is in the **ConfigFiles** folder (which is found on all three servers). I want a way for the package to point to the **ConfigFiles\Cars.dtsConfig** file on each server, but I want to do it without having to provide the name of the server in the directory.

The way I tried it is using **"$(ProjectDir)..\ConfigFiles\Cars.dtsConfig"** which seems to work if I run the package through the .sln file rather than the .dtsx file.

I hope that wasn't too confusing. Let me know if you need anymore info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing some nuance, you don't need to do anything special.

Your package is going to have a hard coded reference to `D:\ConfigFiles\Cars.dtsConfig` It won't matter whether that package is being run from ServerA, ServerB or ServerZ (as long as you have the same file structure on those servers).

By virtue of your asking the question, are you experiencing something different?